# In a geometric sequence $u_1=125$ and $u_6 =1/25$

Tags: geometric-series

In a geometric sequence $u_1=125$ and $u_6 =1/25$.

- a) Find the value of $r$ (the common ratio).
- b) Find the largest value of $n$ for which $S_n < 156.22$.
- c) Explain why there is no value of $n$ for which $S_n > 160$.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Since we are dealing with a geometric sequence, $u_k = 125r^{k-1}$. Can you use this to solve part a)?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$u_6=u_1(r)^{6-1}\implies$$
$$ \frac{1}{5^2}=5^3r^5 \implies$$
$$r^5=(\frac 15)^5$$
$$S_n=u_1+u_2+...+u_n=u_1\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}S_n=\frac{625}{4}=156,25$$
$$\implies (\forall n\ge 1)\;\; S_n\le 156,25<160$$
because $ (S_n) $ is increasing.